# How to open file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/ folder on Mac?

Tags: sqlite, ios5, ios11

I'm trying to use `fileProvider` in iOS 11 and have a database at `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/xxxx/xxx.db`.

I would like to open this folder to open this database in SQLite Manager. How to do this?

Comment: if you want to access the private folder of your own developed application   then download container and the show the contain then you can access the DB

Answer (score 0):

You can also access simulator path by :

1. Click on finder.
2. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.
3. Paste your search path.

You will get the file in your "finder folder" directory.

Comment: But if you want access iPhone file directory it is not access